# How to Update external links in Excel using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, closedxml

I have a workbook with a couple of external links. 
Regularly we need to update the links to point to a new excel database, so I'm making a small windows application to do it automatically.

I'm trying to use OpenXML to get this done. I dont want to use Interop, coz it takes too long to open the file, change the link and then close the workbooks again.

Any Ideas , please let me know. I'm open to using ClosedXML to this as well.

Comment: I've managed to get this done by Interop, but its too slow.
I'm looking at the OpenXML SDK, and the ExternalWorkbookParts is the class from where I can retrieve the list of links, however, I cant find anything to update them

Answer (score 1):

Are you using this on a limited amount of machines? e.g. One laptop for the db admin? If yes I would suggest you use DSN connections in Excel and that you update them from the DSN editor when the db change

See the following in Windows.
C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe

This way any files using these DSN will have updated connections.

Comment: The files will be used over a shared server, so I'm not sure about your solution. This is actually the first time I'm seeing these DSN connections, so thanks for introducing me to something new!

Comment: This depends therefore on the security of the db. If you can give all users accessing the file READ permissions then this should still be feasible. If not I would go with ClosedXML - much more forward than OpenXML.